# What's the difference between these two phrases?

Tags: set-phrases

I understand that both mean `I have a newspaper` but I can't see the difference.

> [僕]{ぼく}は一つ[新聞]{しんぶん}を[持]{も}っています。
>
> [俺]{おれ}は一つ[新聞]{しんぶん}を[持]{も}っている。

Comment: This may sound like a dumb question but what does "I have a newspaper." mean?  You are holding a paper?  I am a J-speaker but I do not really understand your two "Japanese" sentences, either, to be honest.

Comment: Both have different endigs. ~いる and ~います

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 僕は１つXXを持っています。
>   俺は１つXXを持っている。

The latter sounds more casual and masculine because of the use of 俺 and the casual form いる.

Comment: So the first one is for a formal scenary and the secon one for friends?

Comment: Yes, you'd say the first one to your teacher, boss, or someone you don't know, and the second one to friends or families.